# Do high dividend yield stocks generally outperform the market?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, reference-request, factor-models, fundamentals

The only paper I could find is the following:

[Dividend Yield Strategy in the British Stock Market 1994-2007 by Brzeszczynski et al. (2008)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1100623)

It states that a portfolio of stocks with high dividend yields outperforms the broad market most of the time.

Now of course this is only the UK market within a period of a little more than a decade. So I am looking for more papers on this topic covering more markets and longer periods of time.

Comment: Fama/French has portfolios formed on dividend yields (http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html). This could be the starting point for your research.

Comment: Consider that in the US individual investors pay income tax on dividends while university endowments, foundations and pension plans do not. So the answer could get complicated: outperform for which kind of investor?

Comment: @noob2: Normally tax considerations are not part of performance measures.

Comment: there is at least one paper that "proves" that any strategy is the best..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The highly respected [CXO Advisory Group](https://www.cxoadvisory.com/) has done some research on this topic on basis of a suggestion from me. The result is summarized as follows (cited with permission):

> In summary, evidence suggests that high-dividend stock ETFs mostly
>   generate positive alpha with beta less than one relative to SPY, but
>   other performance comparisons to the market are mixed.

After having read the very interesting post I have to say that the case is far from closed but all in all high-dividend stocks don't seem to have a clear edge over the broad market.

The full piece can be found here but most of it is behind a paywall: https://www.cxoadvisory.com/29079/fundamental-valuation/do-high-dividend-stocks-really-beat-the-market/

Answer (score 1):

The [Fama French 1993 paper](https://rady.ucsd.edu/faculty/directory/valkanov/pub/classes/mfe/docs/fama_french_jfe_1993.pdf) analyzed dividends at the end and found that the effects of the observed dividend to price ratio could be fully explained by their book-equity/market-equity ratio.  In other words, it's better to look at book-equity/market-equity ratio rather than dividends.